# onClick does not work for custom component

Tags: reactjs

Why does onClick not work directly on my custom element as shown here? The function chosenResource does not get invoked.

```
return (
    <div>
        {
            resources.map(resource => {
                return (
                    <SelectListItem key={resource.id} onClick={this.chosenResource.bind(this)} resource={resource}  />
                )
            })
        }
    </div>
)
```

However, if I encapsulate my custom element in a div element and have the onClick on the div element then it works.

```
return (
    <div>
        {
            resources.map(resource => {
                return (
                    <div key={resource.id} onClick={this.chosenResource.bind(this)}>
                        <SelectListItem  resource={resource}  />
                    </div>
                )
            })
        }
    </div>
)
```

What is wrong with the first approach?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

@nrgwsth is correct, if you still want to stick with your first approach, you may use:

```
return (
    <div>
        {
            resources.map(resource => {
                return (
                    <SelectListItem key={resource.id} customClickEvent={this.chosenResource.bind(this)} resource={resource}  />
                )
            })
        }
    </div>
)
```

Then, in your `SelectListItem's render()` function, use like this:

```
return (
    <div onClick={this.props.customClickEvent}>
        ...
    </div>
)
```

Comment: To make this a more complete answer you should expand on what nrgwsth said.

Comment: What if you want to handle the onClick in the parent component?

Comment: And BTW customClickEvent could also just be called onClick (to make it look more consistent with the rest), but you do need to implement it yourself in the custom component as @thinhvo0108 has explained.

Answer (score 23):

You can provide `onClick` and other events only on DOM elements.

Answer (score 14):

In react, we have components(ex. `SelectListItem`) and elements(ex.`div`). Elements are the basic building blocks for the component.

Elements are transpiled into plain javascript objects which represent DOM elements where we can bind the dom events like `onCLick`, `onHover` etc.

However Component returns the instance that contains a bunch of elements but does not correspond to the DOM element.

SO if you want to bind DOM event we should do it on the react elements, not in components.

In the above code, onClick event is passed down as props to the component which can be seen by logging the props of the compoenet.